# unexpected result with numpy any()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, any

most probably I'm missing something on the `any()`function, it says: 
`Returns True if any of the elements of a evaluate to True.`

So in my case below, I would expect `true` as an output, as one element `count[0]` 
is larger than 2. However, the output is `FALSE`.

What stupid mistake am I doing?!

minimal example:

```
count = np.zeros(10)
count[0] += 4
count[5] += 1
print(np.any(count,axis=0) > 2)
```

Comment: You have the `any` and `>2` tests in the wrong order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# parentheses:

np.any(count,axis=0)
#output: True

np.any(count, axis=0)>2
# is a boolean expression. It evaluates to False, because True is not larger than 2.

# So:
np.any(count>2, axis=0)

# should do what you want
```